# can we use any other special character than a dot to separate routing keys in RabbitMQ topic exchange

Tags: php, rabbitmq

Can we use some other special character to separate the routing keys in a RabbitMQ topic exchange implementation.
As an example can I use something like following.

*##orange##lazy*

here "##" is my routing key delimiter.

Comment: I see this in the docs, is this hash notation a wildcard syntax? "* (star) can substitute for exactly one word. # (hash) can substitute for zero or more words." https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-php.html

Comment: yeah that's correct @Scuzzy . It's explained in the documentation. But we can't use any other special character other than "*"  or "#" for this right?

Comment: Unless you have access to source code or their API has instructions on how to change the delimeter, I doubt it.

Answer (score -2):

```
$string='##orange##lazy';
$pieces = explode("##", $string);
var_dump($pieces);
```

Sure, you can use explode function.